# remove everything between parentheses bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Stringfield1 has the following

```
Sales Support (130)
Product Support (110)
IT
```

needs to be

```
Sales Support
Product Support 
IT
```

trying
`regexp_substr(Stringfield1 ,'\((.*?)\)',1,1,null,1)`

but I can't seem to get it to work, what am I doing wrong?
using big query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `regexp_replace(Stringfield1, r'\(\d+\)$', '')`

if applied to sample data in  your question - output is

[image]